# Need help plotting line chart with five lines using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This input data is from dput:

```
structure(list(Player = c("deGrom", "deGrom", "deGrom", "deGrom", 
"deGrom", "deGrom", "deGrom", "Wheeler", "Wheeler", "Wheeler", 
"Wheeler", "Wheeler", "Wheeler", "Syndergaard", "Syndergaard", 
"Syndergaard", "Syndergaard", "Matz", "Matz", "Matz", "Matz", 
"Matz", "Stroman", "Stroman"), GSc = c(66, 70, 77, 77, 79, 78, 
79, 76, 70, 64, 70, 62, 70, 69, 73, 81, 62, 68, 62, 69, 68, 70, 
63, 75)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have a data frame MetsGS3 with the data above.

I want to use ggplot to create a line chart with a different color line for each of the five players. The x-axis will contain the numbers 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12. The y-axis will contain the game scores (GS2). I want the x-axis label to be Player and the y-axis label to be Game Score.

This code does not work, and I need help getting it to work. I know it is missing elements.

```
ggplot(MetsGS, aes(x=MetsGS$Player, y=GSc, colour = MetsGS$Player) + geom_line(size=1.2) + ggtitle("Mets Game Score Game Scores")
```

The last time I ran the above ggplot code in RStudio I got this error:
"Error: Incomplete expression: ggplot(MetsGS, aes(x=MetsGS$Player, y=GSc, colour = MetsGS$Player) + geom_line(size=1.2) + ggtitle("Mets Game Score Game Scores")"

Thanks in advance,
Howard

Comment: Ok, 2 problems: One, you have closed the parentheses around the `aes` call, but you are missing a `)` to close the first `ggplot` (that's the incomplete expression). Second, since you have passed the `MetsGS` data frame as a first argument to `ggplot`, you no longer need the `MetsGS$` bit in the rest. This is basic stuff: have a look at `?ggplot2::ggplot`, especially the Examples section.

Comment: Thanks jakub. I plan to look at what is in the Examples section.

Comment: In addition to the typo pointed out above, you say "The x-axis will contain the numbers 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12." but those numbers aren't in your data. Instead, you've put the categorical variable Player on the x-axis. It's unclear what you're trying to do, but fix the typo first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some data missing in your dataset. I can't find how you are defining `x` as a number comprised between 2 and 12.

So, I assumed that for each player, each line containing the name of the player correspond to a different game. So, I create a new column using `dplyr` as this (I called your dataframe `d`):

```r
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(Player) %>% mutate(Number = seq_along(Player)*2) 

# A tibble: 24 x 3
# Groups:   Player [5]
   Player    GSc Number
   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 deGrom     66      2
 2 deGrom     70      4
 3 deGrom     77      6
 4 deGrom     77      8
 5 deGrom     79     10
 6 deGrom     78     12
 7 deGrom     79     14
 8 Wheeler    76      2
 9 Wheeler    70      4
10 Wheeler    64      6
# … with 14 more rows
```

and plot it like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(Player) %>% mutate(Number = seq_along(Player)*2) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=Number, y=GSc, colour = Player)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.2) + 
  ggtitle("Mets Game Score Game Scores")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2,14, by = 2))
```

[image]

Does it look what you are looking for ? If not, can you clarify your question

Comment: dc37, thank you very much for what you wrote. Though the chart did not exactly match what I was seeking, the excellent information in your response enabled me to  create the chart I needed.

Comment: Glad that my answer helps you to figure out your issue ;)